# ASPOSE LINQ Reporting Engine tag break cell format

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose.words

1. The tag break the word layout when the tag name is long
2. The image tag was hidden when textbox is not large enough
   [image]

How could I add the tags without breaking the word layout and make image tag not hidden?

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ Reporting Engine tags are simple text so they behaves the same way as simple text in MS Word document. You can format the tags with different font to make them more readable in the template.
https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/template-syntax/

Comment: thank u Alexey for your suggestion, I make the tag font smaller, but the font size affective the generated context, I want the generated content to have the same font as the original, what should  i do

Comment: Yes, Aspose.Words uses the same font as a tag to format the value.  I am afraid there is no way to have a pretty formatted template, since tags are simple text they behaves as simple text and affects the layout of the template due to the flow nature of MS Word documents..